# How to enable fileinfo.so

Tags: php

i am using xampplite1.7.2 which is using PHP 5.3 but when i use the fileinfo function its giving me error

> Call to undefined function
>   finfo_open()

I don't know rather my fileinfo.so is enabled or not. So please someone guide me how to check and how to enable it if its not enabled.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you should take a look at the output of `phpinfo()` To know if the extension is enabled.

The documentation stats that it's enabled by default on PHP 5.3, so make sure your PHP version is >= 5.3. If not there is a [PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/fileinfo).

> This extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0. Before this time, fileinfo was a PECL extension but is no longer maintained there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

will tell you if fileinfo.so is loaded

Comment: I checked phpinfo(). It is showing SplFileInfo is enable. is this mean that fileinfo is enabled?? and if it is enable then why i am getting this error.